# While loop in php that displays the current date

Tags: php

I need to use a while loop in php to display the current date number of the month. The display needs to display "Hello", rather than the number. It also has to display "Hello" the number of times equal to the current date. So, today is Feb. 27. Hello should be displayed 27 times. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$x = date(d);
while($x == date(d)) {
echo "$x Hello<br>";
$x++;
}
```

All I am returning is 27Hello. I don't know how to convert $x to "Hello". Then increment that the same number of times as the current day(27).

Comment: 1) Set x to 0 2) Enter the while loop as long as x is smaller than the current date 3) Increment x in every iteration 4) Don't output x just output hello

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php => `Notice: Use of undefined constant d - assumed 'd'` as per AbraCadaver's comment below. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - those `(d)` are treated as constants. http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php - *"All I am returning is 27Hello"* - ***Impossible***. Not with what you posted for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reseach bit more next time, before posting question ..

```
<?php
$x = date('d');

while($x!=0) {
 echo "$x Hello<br>"; //if you want number..
 echo "Hello<br>";  //to print just hello
 $x--;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: `Notice: Use of undefined constant d - assumed 'd'`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I am new to Php and I have looked for the info for quite a while now. All I had to do was decrement?! I was trying to increment. Do you know of any other websites I can check out for help? Thanks for you time.

Comment: I can't see why this answer could possibly work; not with `$x = date(d);` it won't. As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php `echo date('l \t\h\e jS');`. - And accepting this answer *"as is"*, would only be sending out the wrong message.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no offence, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php  format param 'd' returns number of days, i just corrected hist syntax and posted .. anyways always welcome for suggestions if this is not an optimal ..

Comment: @AbraCadaver added quotes & updated answer, the notice does not appear now.. I had checked the output before posting, but missed that notice... Thanks for pointing out ..

Comment: @Aamir *"format param `'d'` returns number of days"*.  Indeed and agreed. But the missing quotes around it `date(d)`, is/was treated as a constant http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php - It's best to give proper syntax and for future visitors to the question/answer who may not know this. You know, and I know... but others who are not familiar with the syntax, probably won't know what to do. *"Food for thought"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, i have already updated the same after seeing AbraCadever comment .. :)